# Searching in string array to get list of specifc values starting with speacific charecter ?How to

Tags: c#, linq

This is my string array

```
 "Ararangua  AAA", "LOS-Lagos LOS", "ARRABURY QL AUSTRALIA  AAB", "Babrey BSA" , "lahore LHE"
```

i am performing search on it that all values out of 199989 string values that start with charecter 'a' or 'A' must be returned in another array of string my value to be searhed is at 1 index can you tell me any other simple mechanism to get the array of string only those who start with a

```
       for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = arr[0][1];

            }
```

Comment: Contents refer to the comma separated strings?

Comment: Try something like : `string[] arr =contents.Split(',')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you want to filter your list of strings to those whose second character is either 'a' or 'A'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be done in LINQ.somthing like this

```
string contents = "\"Ararangua  AAA\",\"LOS-Lagos LOS\", \"ARRABURY QL AUSTRALIA  AAB\"";

    var data =  (from a in contents.Split(',')
                 let t = a.Replace("\"",string.Empty).Trim()
                 where t[0] =='a' || t[0] =='A'
                 select t).ToArray();
```

Comment: Great code, but doesn´t this only get the 'a' or 'A' values?

Comment: Yes,and this is what OP wants; if I understood correctly.

Comment: OK, he changed the question, then this would fit :-) , but still with the restriction to have no commas in his values.

Comment: `string[] results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s[2].Equals('a') || s[2].Equals('A'));`

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] arr = contents.Split(new char[]{','});
```

Comment: now how to check `arr[0]` whose value is `"\"Ararangua    AAA\""` that starting with A or a

Comment: @MarcelTheis He didn't specify any comma in his examples.

Comment: ` char c = arr[0][1];` got it

Comment: searching left bro please if you can check this again edited

Comment: @neelajay If this is the answer, don't forget to label as so.

Comment: actually @MarcelTheis also given best answer closer to solution you are lucky i have no comma in values but  searching part left in arr[] against char making another arr1[]

Comment: @neelajay You shouldn't keep changing the question as you get answers.

Answer (score 0):

To seperate your values, you should use:

```
string[] arr = contents.Split("\",");
```

This gives you every single value of your string. After that you have to sort your array of course, as it is not in alphabetical order. And adjust your values by arr[x].Replace("\"", String.Empty) to remove the leading quotation marks.

Comment: Error   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'